# How to array_push unique values inside another array

Tags: php, arrays, unique, array-push

I have two arrays:

```
$DocumentID = array(document-1, document-2, document-3, document-4,
                    document-5, document-4, document-3, document-2);

$UniqueDocumentID = array();
```

I want to push the unique objects inside of `$documentid` array to `$UniqueDocumentID` array.

I can't use `array_unique()` as it copies the key of its predecessor array and I want sequential keys inside the `$UniqueDocumentID` array.

Comment: `$UniqueDocumentID = array_unique($DocumentID);`???

Comment: First start by creating a valid array in `$DocumentID`

Comment: I can't use array_unique as it copies the **key** of its predecessor array and I want sequential keys inside the $UniqueDocumentID array, that is why I need to push objects into $UniqueDocumentID array to keep them in a sequence of  ascending order of **key**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `foreach()` through `$DocumentID` and check for the current value in `$UniqueDocumentID` with `in_array()` and if not present add it.  Or use the proper tool:

```
$UniqueDocumentID = array_unique($DocumentID);
```

To your comment about wanting sequential keys:

```
$UniqueDocumentID = array_values(array_unique($DocumentID));
```

The long way around:

```
$UniqueDocumentID = array();

foreach($DocumentID as $value) {
    if(!in_array($value, $UniqueDocumentID)) {
        $UniqueDocumentID[] = $value;
    }
}
```